# Get list of consumed in-app purchases in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm working on an android app with in-app purchases, which when bought are immediately consumed.

**Is there a way to get the list of all purchased items from the Google Play Service**, which have already been consumed by the user? For example to avoid problems when a user might uninstall and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that once you consume a purchase, it is again available for repurchase. Hence it you want to be able to switch between devices, it may not be appropriate to "consume" purchases. Rather, after purchase, do not consume the item and that information will be shared between devices - provided they use the same account of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`getPurchases()`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases):

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```